# How to integrate jsreport to meteor application

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, jsreport

Can anyone help me how to integrate jsreport to meteor application and how to use it to generate pdfs using data from database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the node package for that.
Link:: [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsreport)

> Don't forget to import the package before use.

You can also check the following example also which is using jsreport-client.
Link:: [Here](http://jsreport.net/learn/nodejs-client)

Comment: I tried but didn't work. Can you explain me how jsreport work?
What are the options we have?